# Rounding numbers in jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

Cant understand why this code is not rounding values in Block 1/2/3 when you slide. [Here is the link for this example.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/RWExLO)

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range-min").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value + ",000" + " руб.");

            $('.number').each(function () {
                var curval = $(this).data('summary');
                var newval = parseInt($(this).val(curval - ui.value * 0.08))

                if (!curval >= $(this).val()) {
                    $(this).val('It is free now')
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see any rounding being done when you set the value to a float with `$(this).val(curval - ui.value * 0.08)`. You probably meant to put the `parseInt` inside the `val()`?

Comment: Haha. Thanks alot. Obvious things make me suffer. Now its fine.

Comment: Please don't title jQuery stuff [tag:jq], that's a command-line JSON-parsing utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to do too much in this code:

```
var newval = parseInt($(this).val(curval - ui.value * 0.08))
```

This part changes the value, but it doesn't do any rounding:

```
$(this).val(curval - ui.value * 0.08)
```

It returns a jQuery object, which you're then calling with `parseInt()`, resulting in `newval` being `NaN`.

Do this instead:

```
var newval = parseInt(curval - ui.value * 0.08);
$(this).val(newval);
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyrYvm)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. It helped. I'll mark this answer as correct!